# Less technical term to describe how often a recurring schedule repeats itself?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, technical

Defining a recurring schedule requires two steps:

1. How often the schedule repeats itself (e.g. weekly, every 2 weeks, every 3 weeks, etc.)
2. Inside each repetition, when the recurrently scheduled event actually happens (e.g. 1:00PM on Tuesday and Thursday of the first week, and 3:00PM on Monday and Wednesday of the second week)

The combination of these two things can be called "schedule" or "frequency" or another simple term.

But what is a good name for step #1 alone?  Microsoft Outlook calls it "Recurrence Pattern" which to me seems intimidatingly technical. Is there a plainer English term that will work instead?

The word will be used as a label in a website form where users choose how frequently (how many weeks) the schedule repeats itself.

Comment: As far as the meanings of the English terms is concerned, you can call the combination of 1 and 2 a "schedule" but 1 *on its own* is the "frequency". Having said that, Joe Blow's answer is probably of more practical use in your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've faced this problem many times!

the only solution is to remember that:

**they will be seeing the 'question word' AND INDEED the 'selections' at the same time.**

I find this to be critical in UI, these days, since everything is so tricky.

So my solution is:

```
Repeats ... < daily >< weekly >< monthly >

On ... < Monday >< Tuesday >< Friday >< Saturday >
```

SO, in a sense the answer is:

**"Repeats"** and **"On"**

Note that even if you don't dynamic it, it still looks good:

```
Repeats ... < daily >< weekly >< monthly >

On ... < Monday >< Tuesday >< Friday >< Saturday >< 1st >< 15th > .. etc
```

Hope it helps!

This is a very useful trick in such UI.  **Use the context of having both parts visible.**  After all, when writing you have "whole sentences" available to you, not just words.  And it's analogous in this "on screen" problem.

Comment: This works. Will need to be translated carefully into other languages where implied sentence structure can't be relied on, but for English this is a great solution. Thanks!